# better way to verify jwt token for angular app deployed on nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, angular-routing

I have created a server using the express framework. I have implemented the JWT. I have created an angular app then copied to the public folder. Then used

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

to make this public. Now I want to authenticate my angular routes. Now there could be a call for the URL that will be URL of angular routing like `localhost:7000/a`, `localhost:7000/b` and so on. Additionally, there will be calls for the actual files like CSS, images or other files.

So I have used a middleware to intercept all the server calls.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   let pwt = req.cookies ? req.cookies.pwt : null;
   jwt.verify(pwt, process.env.SECRET_KEY, (err, decoded) => {
       if (decoded) {
           res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
       } else {
           let callbackUrl = encodeURIComponent("http://" + req.headers.host + req.originalUrl);
           res.redirect(process.env.AUTH_SERVER + "/auth?_r=" + callbackUrl);
        }
   });
});
```

I am checking the jwt token and return the index.html file for each request. when there is call for image or any other CSS files it returns the index.html file.

One way is to make an array of Angular routing URLs and serve the index.html file only if `req.originalUrl` is from that list. But this is not the good approach, as the server should not have the knowledge of app routing. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this is to implement [routes](https://angular.io/guide/router) in angular and secure it there if you are building SPA, but with express middleware just secure your API request from your angular app.